# Proper meaning of 'algebra'.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, terminology, definition

In our algebra course,several times we are introduced to the concept of an algebra.An algebra over a field $F$ is roughly a ring and an $F$-vector space.An algebra homomorphism is basically a ring homomorphism and a linear transformation.But then in our module theory course,our instructor introduced the term 'algebra' a bit differently.He told us that a commutative ring $A$ together with a ring homomorphism $f:R\to A$ (Where $R$ is a commutative ring) is called an $R$-algebra.Then he showed that if there exists such an $f$ ,then $A$ is an $R$-module.But these two definitions do not seem to match.I don't think they are equivalent.Then what is the connection between these two things?

Comment: How my professor described it, (in a very elementary way) is a vector space with defined vector multiplication. The idea can easily transfer to modules. Think of sets of matrices of the same size. If they are not square - can't multiply; if they are square- can multiply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A *$K$-algebra* $A$ is  a vector space over a field $K$ equipped with a bilinear product, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_over_a_field). If it is not necessarily associative or commutative it is often called a *non-associative algebra*.

For a commutative ring $R$, an *$R$-algebra* $A$ is, as you said, is a ring with identity together with a ring homomorphism $f\colon R \to A$ such that the subring $f(R)$ of $A$ is contained within the center of $A$."

Reference: [What exactly is an $R$-algebra?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/349968/what-exactly-is-an-r-algebra?rq=1)

For the difference or similarities of the two notions see some posts here:

[Definition of R-Algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3970772/definition-of-r-algebra)

[Difference between an R algebra and an algebra as described by Rudin](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4168349/difference-between-an-r-algebra-and-an-algebra-as-described-by-rudin)

The first definition includes Lie algebras, Jordan algebras, alternative algebras, flexible algebras, Jacobi-Jordan algebras and many more.

Comment: Isn’t $A$ also described as a module, for the purposes of $R$-algebra?

Comment: @FShrike Yes, the first reference gives some details:"An $R$-algebra is an 
$R$-module, which also has a ring structure, etc. "